# powershell - output trimming

Tags: powershell, output, one-liner

I am trying to read valid values of network adapter speed settings, but it looks like PowerShell does not output everything. According to the GUI network adapter settings window, there is '100 Mbps Full Duplex' and '1000Mbps Full Duplex' missing in the list of PowerShell outputted values.

```
PS> Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty Ethernet -Displayname 'Link Speed & Duplex' | fl ValidDisplayValues

ValidDisplayValues : {Auto Negotiation, 10 Mbps Half Duplex, 10 Mbps Full Duplex, 100 Mbps Half Duplex...}
```

I've tried to play with `ft` `out-string` and `write-host` but haven't had any luck. How do I output a complete list?

UPDATE: I've tried adding [GUI view](https://www.imgpaste.net/image/KdLyC3) to my network adapter speed settings for better understanding of my problem.

Comment: If anyone will experiment: Replace string `Link Speed & Duplex` in command with string `*speed*`, because it depend on NIC driver....

Comment: My system doesn't even have 'Link Speed & Duplex', this might be a vendor/driver specific property?

Comment: Have you read my comment?

Comment: Yes, and there isn't anything similar on my system neither...

Comment: What output are you expecting? 1 value per line?

Comment: Expect more values, where three dots are now. The list is incomplete... Supose the three dots represent some cutted info... See question update.

Comment: @Dennis You ma have a look to GUI details of your NIC adapter, maybe nic vendor take a different name.

Comment: That is just because the default way PowerShell **displays** it and because it doesn't fit the width of the screen, it gets truncated. Try `(Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name Ethernet -Displayname 'Link Speed & Duplex').ValidDisplayValues'`

Comment: I didn't see a point looking for it in the GUI if it's not included in PowerShell by the driver...

Comment: @Theo If it's not there you can't show it regardless.

Comment: @Dennis True of course, but in this case, the OP claims the values should be there. Looking at the output he displayed, this is typically a case of displaying truncated output. On my Dutch system, I need to use `LAN-verbinding` instead of `Ethernet`  and have Displayname `Snelheid & duplex` instead of `Link Speed & Duplex`. Personally I think it is a bad idea to have to use **localized** properties, but..

Comment: @Theo Ok, don't know what I was thinking. I do have a value similarly... `Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty | where DisplayName -like '*speed*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for -ExpandProperty of `Select-Object`

```
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty | where DisplayName -like '*speed*' | 
select -first 1 -ExpandProperty ValidDisplayValues

Auto Negotiation
10 Mbps Half Duplex
10 Mbps Full Duplex
100 Mbps Half Duplex
100 Mbps Full Duplex
1.0 Gbps Full Duplex
```

But a more generic lookup would be using the Registry name instead of DisplayName (that are supposed to be localized).

```
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty | where RegistryKeyWord -eq '*SpeedDuplex' | 
select -ExpandProperty ValidDisplayValues
```

Comment: thanks, mented registry names are valuable for me